# make vi start by inserting and then move cursor down

Tags: linux, bash, vim, terminal, vi

so I run this command:

```
vi -c 'startinsert' ~/j_exec.php
```

which will startup vi and the moment vi opens it will enter insert mode immediately

Now j_exec.php will always contain `<?php` in the beginning so I want it so that it will ALSO move the cursor down so that the cursor will start 2 lines BENEATH the `<?php` line right after it executes 'startinsert'

how do I go about modifying this command to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply the line number to go to when starting `vim`, by adding `+N`, e.g.

```
 vi +3 -c 'startinsert' ~/j_exec.php
```